# Showing that a matrix multiplication defines a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-homomorphism

Question: Let $A$ be an $m$ x $n$ matrix. Show that matrix multiplication, $x \to Ax$, defines a homomorphism $\phi$ :$\mathbb R$${^n} \to$ $\mathbb R$${^m}$. 
 I have no notes on this because my professor wants to see if I can answer this before the next class. So far I know that scalar multiplication is given by $av$=$a(a_1,....,a_n)$=$(aa_1,....aa_n)$
 The scalar multiplication $x \to Ax$ "stretches" $x$ by a factor $\vert A \vert$ and  reversing its direction when $A$ is negative (we put quotes around stretches because $Ax$ is shorter than $x$ when $\vert A\vert$ $\lt 1$)
Definition of homomorphism: Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two groups. Then $\phi$ : $G_1 \to G_2$ is called a homomorphism iff $\forall$ $a,b \in G_1$. So $\phi$$(ab)$=$\phi (a)$$\phi (b)$
This all the knowledge or information I have about this problem. I do not know how to show the question

Comment: What are the respective group actions for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$? Does multiplication by $A$ play nicely with it?

Comment: You need to show that $A(x+y) = Ax + Ay$

Comment: I think the $\mathbb R$${^n}$ and $\mathbb R$${^m}$ has to do with the definition of vector spaces. This is new to me as I stated in my question

Comment: So I will have $\phi$ $A$($x+y$)=$\phi (Ax)$ $\phi (Ay)$?

Comment: No, for you, $\phi(x) = Ax$ by definition. And the group multiplication for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is addition, so $xy = x+y$ in your case (where $xy$ here means group multiplication, which is addition in this case).

Comment: @DanRust, I am still confused because if $\phi (x)$= $Ax$ would that mean $\phi (Ax)$=$(x+y)$? If not then yeah, I am still confused about this

Comment: @behold: In your problem, $\phi$ is $A$, i.e. $\phi(x) = Ax$. Now, you just have to prove that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$. Since in your case the group operation is the addition of vectors, you just have to show that $A(x+y) = Ax + Ay$, which is pretty obvious.

Comment: A homomorphism $\phi$ of vector spaces is a mapping that preserves both the addition of vectors and the multiplication by scalars.  Thus, it suffices to show that both $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$ and $\phi(ax)=a\phi(x)$.  If it is only a group homomorphism you want, then scalars do not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all for $\phi: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ such that $\phi(x)=Ax$ implies that $x$ isn't a scalar. $x$ is a vector. With that little tidbit of information, we can conclude that $\phi$ is doing a form of matrix multiplication on the right. Thus for your action we have,
$$\phi(x)= \begin{bmatrix} p_1\\p_2\\\vdots\\p_m
\end{bmatrix},\; \mathrm {s.t.}\: p_k=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{(i,k)}x_i .$$
So let $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$ such that $\phi(x)=\begin{bmatrix} p_1\\p_2\\ \vdots\\ p_m \end{bmatrix}$ and $\phi(y)=\begin{bmatrix} q_1\\q_2\\ \vdots\\ q_m \end{bmatrix}$. It will now be sufficient to prove that $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$. So,

$$\begin{array}{ccc} \phi(x+y) = \begin{bmatrix} r_1\\r_2\\\vdots\\r_m
\end{bmatrix},\; \mathrm {s.t.}\: r_k &=&\sum_{i=1}^n a_{(i,k)}(x_i+y_i)\\ 
&=&\sum_{i=1}^n a_{(i,k)}(x_i)+\sum_{i=1}^n a_{(i,k)}(y_i)\\
\begin{bmatrix} p_1+q_1\\p_2+q_2\\\vdots\\p_m+q_m
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} p_1\\p_2\\ \vdots\\ p_m \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} q_1\\q_2\\ \vdots\\ q_m \end{bmatrix}&=&\phi (x)+\phi(y)
\end{array}$$
as desired.

Comment: very useful. Now when you say $p_k$, that is some arbitrary element right?

Comment: it's an element in the new vector $\phi(x)\in \mathbb R^m$ yes where $1\leq k\leq m$

Comment: same can be said for $\phi (y)$ $\in \mathbb R$${^n}$?

Comment: yep but $\phi(y) \in \mathbb R^m$ and not $\mathbb R^n$. $y\in \mathbb R^n$. This can also be said for $\phi(x+y)\in \mathbb R^m$ as well.

Comment: Now can you show that $\theta: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $\theta (x)=xA$ is also a homomorphism?

Comment: i need to do that for this problem or in general?

Comment: Not really but it is a curious question. And it would help you understand what I did in a better light.  Also mathematicians like solving problems. So I figure giving you a similar problem to work on wouldn't take the fun out of me doing it all for you.

Comment: I will work on your question also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55551/discussion-between-behold-and-sentinel135).